# Hex representaion of bytes in a String

Tags: java, hex

I read somewhere that string 0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA987654321089ABCDEF01234567 is 192 bit (24). Its written that it is a "hex representation of bytes"

I need help on this concept.

PS: This is secret key of TripleDES algorithm.

Comment: unless you don't want 'us' to crack the key, help shall be granted ;) sorry, what's the question?

Comment: I was reading a tutorial (http://www.cryptosys.net/3des.html) on TripleDES encryption where this key was written. Learning purpose man.

Comment: sorry, tahir, really thought, you needed help on TripleDES itself.

Comment: I don't think you can call the key secret anymore though... :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In hexadecimal numbers, you have 16 different digits. These are written using first the ordinary 10 symbols used for decimal digits, 0 through 9. Then the first six letters of the Latin alphabet are used, i.e. A through F.

Since each digit represents a value in the range 0 through F, i.e. one of sixteen possibilities, it holds four bits of information. Thus, in a long string of hex digits, you can compute the total number of bits of information as just four times the number of digits present.

Your example string, "0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA987654321089ABCDEF01234567", is 48 digits. This means it is a 48 * 4 = 192 bit number, in hexadecimal form.

If you're interested in viewing this large number as a sequence of bytes, just take pairs of digits, since each byte is 8 bits. The first (counting from the left) few bytes then become `0x01`, `0x23`, `0x45`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a big number. The only difference between the numbers you are used to (such as "192") is that it's written in using the [hexadecimal number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) instead of the [decimal number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal). The hexadecimal number system uses 16 digits (0-9 and A-F) instead of the 10 you are used to (0-9).

That particular number is equivalent to 27898229935051914480226618602452055732231960245295072615 in decimal notation.

Answer (score 2):

Joachim already explained the theoretical concept. If you want to play around with such numbers yourself in Java, then take a look at `java.math.BigInteger`.

E.g., to convert your hexadecimal number to the decimal or any other system:

```
// the "radix" is 16 because the string represents a hexadecimal number
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(
        "0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA987654321089ABCDEF01234567", 16);

// print the number in decimal (digits 0-9)
System.out.println(bi.toString(10));

// print the number in octal (digits 0-7)
System.out.println(bi.toString(8));
```

Comment: What does this return anyway? Is there any data type in Java that can handle 192 bit long integers. Pardon my ignorance, I am a .net guy.

Comment: BigInteger is this data type. It can hold effectively arbitrary-big integer values (constrained by available memory mostly). It is similar to the `System.Decimal` type except that it has no decimal places (the exact equivalent for `System.Decimal` would be `BigDecimal` in Java).

Comment: If it has no decimal places, wouldn't it be more similar to int or long or something?

Answer (score 1):

```
0123456789ABCDEF FEDCBA9876543210 89ABCDEF01234567
```

3 (hex) keys aka `3 * 8` bytes or`3 * 8 * 8 = 192` bits.

Answer (score 1):

Each character in hexadecimal corresponds to 4 bits.  So for your example, there are 48 characters and 48 * 4 = 192 bits.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to your second question: How does the JVM distinguish between numbers in different bases?

It does not and can not do so! You as a programmer have to support the JVM. If you specify small constants, then you use a prefix to signal either decimal, octal, or hexadecimal base:

```
// A leading zero signals a constant in octal base;
// octal 46 is decimal 38
final int n1 = 046;

// A leading "0x" signals a constant in hexadecimal base;
// hex 3f is decimal 63
final int n2 = 0x3f;

// No prefix refers to a regular decimal number
final int n3 = 12;
```

There are only prefixes for octal, decimal, and hexadecimal base because these are most often used by programmers. Note, that there is no prefix for binary constants!

If you use the `java.math.BigInteger` class like I did in my previous reply to your first question, then you have to specify the base in the constructor:

```
// input numbers in octal, decimal, and hexadecimal;
// Java needs your help to recognize the base!
final BigInteger b8 = new BigInteger("12345", 8);
final BigInteger b10 = new BigInteger("12345", 10);
final BigInteger b16 = new BigInteger("12345", 16);

// output them in decimal system
System.out.println(b8.toString()); // prints "5349"
System.out.println(b10.toString()); // prints "12345"
System.out.println(b16.toString()); // prints "74565"
```